# How do you find out the caller Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have

```
 var X={
     method1 : function(){
                A();
              },
     method2 : function(){
                A();
              },
    
    }

function A(){
       console.log('im from methodNAME of ObjNAME ');
}
```

How can I find out the name of the **method** and **Object** that the function is called from?

Comment: Isnt it an option to just pass it as an argument to the function?

Comment: Two problems here: Objects don't have names. The name of the variable it is assigned to is not an object's name, you won't be able to find it (unless the variable is global). What if an object is assigned to multiple variables? Similar for the functions in your example. Although functions can have names and often have, yours do not, they are *anonymous*.

Comment: Felix Kling :  generally is there any way to find the name of a global Object , in my case X is global..

Comment: Only if you have a reference to the object. Then you can iterate over the properties of `window`, compare their values and if you have a match, you have the name of the variable. But note that if you have to do this, your application is not well designed. You should not have global variables anyway.

Comment: Developing the global objects iteration idea further... If you have a reference to the caller method (e.g. via `A.caller`), you can recursively iterate over all properties of all global objects and check if their properties are this caller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `arguments.caller` but it's not reliable:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/caller

It has been replaced with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller which seems to have reasonable browser support.

Comment: Thanks Ariel ... but the method i will get as a reference ... i want the name of method and object as String ..

Comment: The name of the method as a string you can get from it's [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Name) property which is as non-standard as `caller`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.log(new Error())` within the function and parse the list of stack trace.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You would be better off with `console.trace()`.

Answer (score -1):

The way you defined and called your `A` function the object that `A` is called for will be `DOMWindow` object - that is, the global object.

As for from which method of `X` it is called (which is what you mean by `methodNAME`, I assume) - in the way you defined your methods (defining an anonymous function and assigning ir to a property) you won't be able to get the name.

Had you declared your `X` object like this:

```
var X = {
    method1: function method1() {
        A();
    },
    method2: function method2() {
        A();
    },

}
```

and your `A` function like this:

```
function A() {
    console.log(A.caller);
}
```

then calling:

```
X.method1();
X.method2();
```

would produce console output like this:

```
function method1() {
        A();
    }

function method2() {
        A();
    }
```

which you could then parse and retrieve the name of the calling method.

Or if you defined `A` like this:

```
function A() {
    console.log(A.caller.prototype);
}
```

then the output on would show:

```
method1
method2
```

where `method1` and `method2` are prototype objects - so you'd have to perform some manipulations as well.

EDIT: fixed bad copy/paste = A.caller.prototype -> A.caller.